# Thread Sanitizer does not show all issues in Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading

Thread Sanitizer does not show all issues. for example

```
  private func observeConversationUsers(_ isObserve: Bool, conversationID: String, updated: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        guard isObserveConversationUsers != isObserve else { return }
        isObserveConversationUsers = isObserve

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let conversationUserRef = Database.database().reference().child(MainGateways.chat.description).child(MainGateways.conversationUsers.description).child(conversationID)


            if !isObserve {
                conversationUserRef.removeAllObservers()
                return
            }

            if !self.references.contains(conversationUserRef) { // for example this issue 
                self.references.append(conversationUserRef)
            }

            conversationUserRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snap) in
                if snap.value is NSNull {
                    return
                }
                guard let dict = snap.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
                guard let chatUserActivityModel = Mapper<ChatUserActivityModel>().map(JSON: dict) else { return }
                self.downloadImageProfile(chatUserActivityModel.userID, conversationID: conversationID)
            }, withCancel: { (error) in
                // TODO: - it
            })

            conversationUserRef.observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snap) in

            }, withCancel: { (error) in
                // TODO: - it
            })
        }
    }
```

My diagnostics settings 
[image]

How can I fix it?

**Update:**  I made a very simple example but Xcode does not show an error here, although the isPushSettingsFormVC property is called in another thread

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var isPushSettingsFormVC = false


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // I think here is a data race
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
            self?.isPushSettingsFormVC = false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The Thread Sanitizer does what it does. What's the Stack Overflow question here? This is not a programming issue. If you think you have a legitimate case, or even if not, file a bug with Apple.

Comment: @matt got it, thanks

Comment: Also what version of Xcode is this??? My Scheme editor looks quite different.

Comment: @matt I use Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

Comment: Just to be sure: when you click on the issue navigator, you have **Runtime** selected or **Buildtime**?

Comment: @Honey I have Runtime selected